# Can I force the webkit version in Cordova?

Tags: android, css, cordova, grid, webkit

I was creating an app with Cordova that contains a CSS Grid Layout. The problem is that it shows on some devices and on the others, the elements are on top of each other. I think the problem comes from webkit versions that don't support Grid Layout. So my question is, can I force the use of a certain version of webkit so this works? I also would like to know which version I should force for it to work. Here's [an example of a CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#Result)

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Cordova uses the webview app that is installed in the device by default. If you wish to use another webview, you need to embed it in your app. Something like [Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) can assure you to use only the webview you provide.

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you! Can I specify the webview version with webview+ ?

Comment: So, I tried it but the problem is that Crosswalk uses an old version of the webview. It made it worse, it doesn't even work on the devices it was working on before.

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this? Ive got the same issue. I love css grid but, its not supprted esp android 4.4.